Adding a triangle shape to point to Showcase.withWidget
So i am using Showcase.withWidget constructor from ShowcaseView, which remove the triangle shape that point to the targetShapeBorder,
how can add it to my code. I just want to add the triagle shape that point to the targetShape
code
Showcase.withWidget(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
      targetShapeBorder: CircleBorder(),
      container: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    title,
                    style: soraBold.copyWith(
                      color: AppColors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Gap(10),
                  Text(
                    description,
                    style: soraBold.copyWith(
                      color: AppColors.black87,
                      fontSize: 12.sp,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: ShowCaseWidget.of(context).dismiss,
                child: Icon(Icons.close),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      key: globalKey,
      // title: title,
      // description: description,
      child: child,
    )


Try to use flutter's package super_tooltip.
